# Why doesn't this work? (question about extending built in models)

Tags: model, resource-model

```
// In a controller or cron script
$order_model = Mage::getModel('mypackage_module/order')->load($id);
$order_model->processStuff();

// in the model class
class Mypackage_Module_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
function processStuff() {
  var_dump($this->getEntityId()); // "null"
}
```

the instance of Mypackage_Module_Model_Order was loaded using the load() call above, so why is getEntityId() null? What is the best practice/"Magento" way of making the model do some model processing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need `getModel()` rather than `loadModel()`

Answer (score 1):

Just gave it a test and it should work, however i can tell you that it will return null if the order "entity_id" does not exist

```
$id = 1;
$order = Mage::getModel('mypackage_module/order')->load($id);
$order->processStuff();

class Mypackage_Module_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
{
    public function processStuff()
    {
        var_dump($this->getEntityId()); // "null"
    }
}
```

So if order id 1 exists it should dump `string(1) "1"` else it will be NULL